# iPad orientation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xamarin.ios, notifications, orientation

I have question regarding changing orientation on iPad.

I use MonoTouch, but if Obj-C programmers can help, it will be just as great.

First of all, I figured out if I provide different splash screen images for different orientations, app will show the right one. This can be done for any orientation, such as "Default-LandscapeLeft.png", or generic one "Default-Landscape.png".

All of my images are of correct dimensions and yet, when I start it in portrait mode, it shows it enlarged. All of other modes work perfectly well.

Second problem is I want my app to continue to be in that orientation after my first controller appear. At the moment, it shows portrait in any case. I started generating orientation notifications before first controller appeared (UINavigationController), but I think it responds only on orientation changes. After I moved device, it rotates and from that moment, everything works fine. BUT, I want to "inherit" orientation info from my splash screen.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks guys and girls.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images for different orientations: 
Default.png and Default-Landscape.png should be provided + setting the app settings to provide the required orientations.

Second problem:
After creating the first controller call

`myController.WillRotate(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation, 0);`

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for answer. The problems still remain. Splash screens are of correct dimensions, portrait and portraitUpsideDown are same in dimensions, but portrait is somehow zoomed in. And the other problem is solved, thank you. The problem was in adding first view controller after service returned customer data. But now I did it immediately and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Pls check the resolution of the images. My Default.png image is 768x1004 px and Default-Landscape.png is 1024x748 px. These two images work just fine.

Comment: Well, I've hidden StatusBar in Info.plist, so dimensions should be 768x1024 and 1024x768. Portrait is, I'd say, twice as wide and twice as tall, it's not a matter of 20px. Same image when used like Portrait-Upsidedown fits in great.